# Let $\phi : X \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be proper, l.s.c., bounded. Show: $\varphi_n(y) := \inf_{z\in X} \{\phi(z) + nd(y,z)\} \to \phi$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, gradient-flows

I am currently working through a paper on Gradient Flows in Metric Spaces by Philippe Clément and need to verify the following.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete, metric space and $\phi : X \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be proper, lower semi continuous and bounded below. Show that $\varphi_n(y) := \inf_{z\in X} \{\phi(z) + nd(y,z)\}$ converges to $\phi$ and $\varphi_n \in \text{Lip}(X;\mathbb{R})$.

What I have tried: I have tried to show the existing of a minimizer of the $\inf$ in $\varphi_n$. Given the fact that everything there is lower semi continuous and bounded from below, I only needed convergence of a minimizing sequence which I have failed to show thus far.

What bothers me even more is that the convergence (of $\varphi_n$) should be obvious since the second term acts as some kind of penalty term if the minimizer were not to be $z = y$, but I am struggling to put that on paper.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Does $\operatorname{Lip}$ mean globally or locally Lipschitz? and is it part of your question?

Comment: Globally Lipschitz and yes it is part of my question but didn't fit into the headline.

Comment: I updated with a solution for Lipschitz continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sequence of $\varepsilon$-minimizers $z_n$ of the inf in $\phi_n$,
i.e., $z_n$ is such that $\phi(z_n)+nd(y,z_n) \leq \phi(y)+\varepsilon$.
Because $\phi(z_n)$ is bounded from below and $\phi(z_n)\leq \phi(y)-\varepsilon$ this means that
$n d(y,z)$ is bounded. In particular, $z_n\to y$.
By lower semi-continuity it follows that $\phi(y)\leq \liminf \phi(z_n)-\varepsilon
\leq \phi_n(y)-\varepsilon$.
Because $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the convergence follows.

For the Lipschitz constant, let $v,w\in X$.
By triangle inequality of the norm we have
$$
 \phi_n(v)
 =
 \inf_z \{ \phi_(z)+nd(z,v) \}
 \leq 
 \inf_z \{ \phi_(z)+nd(z,w) \} + nd(v,w)
 =
 \phi_n(w)+nd(v,w)
$$

Switching the roles of $v,w$ yields the result with Lipschitz constant $n$.

Comment: By $\varepsilon$-minimizer you mean that $\phi(z_n) + nd(y,z_n)$ is in $\varepsilon$-proximity to the actual minimum, is that correct?

Comment: I've made a correction to my question.

Comment: yes, i have added the information. This way we dont need the existence of a minimum, just infimum